# Silverlight 4 toolkit, charting and lineSeries is null

Tags: silverlight, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I create a Silverlight Chart, with the Silverlight 4 toolkit, the April release.

Consider the following chart:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
  <Charting:Chart Title="Chart to test" Name="MySuperChart">
   <Charting:LineSeries x:Name="MyLineSeries" Title="Something" />
  </Charting:Chart>
 </Grid>
```

So far so good. I can access the Series in the chart by `MySuperChart.Series[0]` But when I try to reference MyLineSeries, it appears to be null.
[image: picture]

[Full view](http://i41.tinypic.com/9k4h7t.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an interesting little gotcha.  It helps if you look a bit under the hood at how the variable `MyLineSeries` is created and assigned.  Navigate to the definition of the `InitializeComponent` method.  You will end up at the MainPage.g.cs generated file.  It will contain this field:-

```
internal System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries MyLineSeries;
```

and in the `InitializeComponent` you will find this line:-

```
this.MyLineSeries = ((System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.LineSeries)(this.FindName("MyLineSeries")));
```

So on the surface of it by the time the call to `InitializeComponent` in your constructor has completed the `MyLineSeries` should have been assigned a value.  However as you can see its still null, hence it can be concluded that `FindName("MyLineSeries")` failed to find the series.  So the question is why did it fail?

**Why Doesn't FindName Work?**

`FindName` searches what is refered to in the documentation as the "object tree", looking for an object that has the name specified (there are added complications of what are known as namescopes but that is not at play here).  Typically objects end up in the "object tree" through common base types like `Panel` or `ContentControl` which have propeties such as `Children` and `Child` respectively.  These properties are specified in the `ContentProperty` attribute on the classes which allows for the UI structure to be described more naturally.  E.g.:-

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton">
  <Image x:Name="MyImage" ... />
</Button>
```

Instead of

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton">
  <Button.Child>
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" ... />
  </Button.Child>
</Button>
```

The `Chart` control, on the other hand, is not a simple `Panel` derivative and has a lot more work to do to build its UI.  In the case of the `Chart` the `ContentPropertyAttribute` specifies the `Series` collection parameter.  This allows your more natural Xaml:-

```
<Charting:Chart Title="Chart to test" Name="MySuperChart">
  <Charting:LineSeries x:Name="MyLineSeries" Title="Something" />
</Charting:Chart>
```

However because `Chart` has a lot of extra work in order do determine what exactly should be in the "object tree" that will represent its final UI the series collection items don't immediately become part of the "object tree".  As result the `FindName` in the `InitializeComponent` simply doesn't find them.

**Work Around - Option 1**

You could use your knowledge of the ordinal position of "MyLineSeries" in the chart to handle the assignment of a `MyLineSeries` variable in the constructor.  Remove the `x:Name="MyLineSeries"` from the Xaml then in code:-

```
public partial MainPage : UserControl
{
  private LineSeries MyLineSeries;

  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    MyLineSeries = (LineSeries)MySuperChart.Series[0];
  }
}
```

**Work Around - Option 2**

You could wait until the series is available in the "object tree" which is true once the containing `UserControl` has fired its `Loaded` event:-

```
public partial MainPage : UserControl
{
  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (s, args) =>
    {
      MyLineSeries = (LineSeries)FindName("MyLineSeries");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you say it's kind of a bug? That they don't parse the x:Name?

Comment: @Snake: The x:Name does get parsed but there is an assumption on the part of the auto-generated code that the element can be found in the "object tree" at the time InitializeComponent is executed.  I'm not sure I would categorise this as a bug.

Comment: @AnyhonyWJones: actually your workaround 2 does not work. It doesn't find the name.

Comment: @Snake: My Bad, your right. I was writing from experience with SL3 and Nov09 toolkit.  I've just tested the same in SL4 with April09 toolkit and the second option no longer works.  That's quite irritating. :(

Comment: Yes it is. While I can use the first fix, I don't like it. But thanks!

Comment: @Snake:  Actually since I got that wrong it got me thinking whether my understanding of how SL3 behaved is correct.  Turns out not quite.  The event you want is the `Loaded` event on the containing `UserControl`.  This works in both SL3 and SL4. I've tweaked my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AnyhonyWJones I'm sorry, but it still doesn't work. When the event is fired FindName still returns null. Pitty.

Comment: @Snake:  Strange, I guess that approach isn't reliable then, it works in my testing but I suppose that doesn't guarantee it will work in all scenarios.  Option 1 it is then. :(

Comment: this sucks. it used to work! took me 2 hours to figure out i hadn't broken something elsewhere and to eventually find this thread. anybody know if this is reported as a bug?

Comment: Just wanted to report that workaround option 2 works for me in silverlight 5.